# How to find the numerical/digit in list of strings and replace 1 if numerical/digit exist else 0?

Tags: python, python-3.6, data-analysis, python-3.7

```
lst = ['ihave10apples','mystudentneedgallons','Iwant20computers','MystudentsneedaDellChromebook3120andGoogleEDUManagementConsoleLicense.' ]
```

so there are digits in the list of string, for example, `lst[0]` has `10` as digit so how to replace entire string with `1` and similarily in `lst[1]` there is no digit in string how it'll be replaced with `0`.

Comment: I'd suggest: 1) format the "lst = [..." part as code. 2) include the desired output so people can understand what you want faster and more accurately

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether a word has a digit with something like:

```
any(letter.isdigit() for letter in word)
```

This will return a boolean value depending on whether the word has a digit. You can expand this to a list of words with another level of list comprehension and also convert the boolean to a `1` or `0` in the process:

```
lst = ['ihave10apples','mystudentneedgallons','Iwant20computers','Mystudentsneedtabletstodoallthethingsthatwillmakethemsuccessfulinthis21stcenturylearningenvironment.','MystudentsneedaDellChromebook3120andGoogleEDUManagementConsoleLicense.' ]

nums = [int(any(i.isdigit() for i in w)) for w in lst]
print(nums)
```

result:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```